# I've installed XAMPP but I cannot start MySQL

Tags: 16.04, mysql, xampp

[image]
[image]

I've installed XAMPP but I cannot start MySQL and phpmyadmin is not working.

But I installed MySQL Workbench and that *is* working.

Answer (score 0):

Please look for where your phpmyadmin config file is ( should be in the phpmyadmin folder) and open terminal and run:

```
sudo chmod 700 /path/to/config.inc.php
```

Now restart `apache server`and `mysql`:

```
sudo apche2ctl restart
sudo systemctl restart mysql
```

Comment: i'll change it but it is not work

Comment: restart apache server with `sudo apche2ctl restart`

Comment: i'll restart pc and try it but it is not work

Comment: Please run `systemctl status  mysql` and paste into your question, and what error are you still seeing?

Comment: I don't get your last comment!

Comment: i'll run systemctl status mysql and it is "mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2017-09-09 11:34:46 +0530; 6h ago
 Main PID: 1124 (mysqld)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─1124 /usr/sbin/mysqld
"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65343/discussion-between-george-and-vj-ranga).

Comment: Tje problem is that the answer is WRONG. The file needs to be readable by the webserver, but *not* the world. E.g. change owner to www-data, and mode to 700 or similar. No need to restart anything after changing.

Comment: @vidarlo I totally read that wrong, waoh and we spent more than an hour fixing it.